# Where is the Profile2 field data hiding?

Tags: users

I created a couple of different profile types in Profile2. I then register new accounts through /admin/people/add user (my-profile-type). All of my custom fields show up, and I enter the data accordingly. However, when I go back to the user's profile to edit it, the data isn't there.

Am I missing something obvious? Another post here said there was a button in the admin that gives access to the profile2 fields - but I don't see anything like that?

Answer (score 2):

Each profile type comes up as a second-level tab on the user edit page, like this (using admin theme):

[image: screenshot]

'Parent Information' is a profile type, and the 'Account' link is for the normal edit page.

If those tabs are missing from your theme I'd have a look at page.tpl.php to make sure you're outputting the tabs correctly.

Comment: That's a great place to look Clive - I bet I borked up the tab output just as you suspected. Thanks for taking the time to reply, I really appreciate it.

Comment: No worries, it took me ages to work that out first time I installed that module too!